# Adobe Animate - Controlling outside movie clip on MouseOver

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, adobe

I've created HTML5-canvas with movie clip on it using Adobe Animate CC 2017. This clip has buttons that rotate in a circle.

Example: http://trinidadpena.com/testing/animate/MS_Holiday_2016.html

I'd like the the buttons to highlight when you roll over and for the clip to stop rotating. But I can't get it work on just MouseOver (eiffel tower, example)

```
var frequency = 3;
stage.enableMouseOver(frequency);
this.eiffel_tower.addEventListener("mouseover", fl_MouseOverHandler_4);

function fl_MouseOverHandler_4()
{

    this.parent.stop();

}
```

It works just fine on MouseClick (big ben, example).

```
this.big_ben.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler_4.bind(this));

function fl_MouseClickHandler_4()
{
    this.parent.stop();
}
```

It works on MouseOver if I add code to trigger an alert box (state of liberty, example). But it breaks again if I delete the alert box code.

```
var frequency = 3;
stage.enableMouseOver(frequency);
this.stat_of_lib.addEventListener("mouseover", fl_MouseOverHandler_5);

function fl_MouseOverHandler_5()
{

    alert("Moused over");
    this.parent.stop();
}
```

I haven't worked in ActionScript in a long time. What am I doing wrong? How can I get the buttons to stop the clips rotation when you rollover?

Thanks in advance for your help! I'm pulling out my hair over here.

Comment: For the HTML5-Canvas document-types in Adobe Animate, you code in JavaScript, not in ActionScript, though!

Comment: Thanks for edit. I took out Actionscript from the tags. Much apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you survey the code that is *"working just fine!":*

```
this.big_ben.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler_4.bind(this));
```

you'll be get noticed to the [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method:

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its `this` keyword set to the provided value..

Thus, when the "click" handler gets triggered (i.e. the `fl_MouseClickHandler_4()` function), the `this`, used inside the function, would expectedly point to the movie clip-- causing it to "stop"; *while* it will correctly point to the "unexpected" HTML window-object in the other handlers (where you haven't adjust the reference of the `this` object using the `bind()` method.)

So, one way to resolve the issue is to similarly call the `bind()` method on the other handlers to adjust the `this` variable appropriately :) e.g:

```
this.eiffel_tower.addEventListener("mouseover", fl_MouseOverHandler_4.bind(this));
```